# String/List/Array problem in a Python Markov Chain

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, markov-chains

I was recently making or actually copy pasting a Markov Chain from this video.
While running this I got various string error and list error, but this guy seemed to have an errorless code. So what am I doing wrong here?

Code >>

```
import random as r
print ('Hello to my text generator')
print ('This will generate text from the data which you enter')
#author = input("What is the Author's name? >> ")
#title = input("What is the name of this story? >>")
data = "A short story is a piece of prose fiction that typically can be read in one sitting and focuses on a self-contained incident or series of linked incidents, with the intent of evoking a single effect or mood.The short story is a crafted form in its own right. Short stories make use of plot, resonance, and other dynamic components as in a novel, but typically to a lesser degree. While the short story is largely distinct from the novel or novella/short novel, authors generally draw from a common pool of literary techniques.Short story writers may define their works as part of the artistic and personal expression of the form. They may also attempt to resist categorization by genre and fixed formation.Short stories have deep roots and the power of short fiction has been recognized in modern society for hundreds of years.As William Boyd, the award-winning British author and short story writer has said:seem to answer something very deep in our nature as if, for the duration of its telling, something special has been created, some essence of our experience extrapolated, some temporary sense has been made of our common, turbulent journey towards the grave and oblivion.[1]In terms of length, word count is typically anywhere from for short stories, however some have words and are still classed as short stories. Stories of fewer than words are sometimes referred to as short short stories, or flash fiction  Hello"
order = int(input("What should the order be? >> "))
length = int(input('How long should this "story" be? >> '))
class MarkovAlgorithm:
    def __init__(self, order):
        self.order = order
        self.graph = {}
        self.text = None
        return
    def train(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.text= self.text.split()
        for i in range(0, (len(self.text) - self.order + 1)):
            word = tuple(self.text[i: i+self.order])
            nextWord = self.text[self.order]
            if nextWord in self.graph:
                self.graph[word].append(nextWord)
            else:
                self.graph[word] = nextWord
    def generate(self, length):
        index = r.randint(0, len(self.text) - self.order)
        startingWords = self.text[index: index+self.order]
        for i in range(length):
            orginalState = tuple(startingWords[len(startingWords) - self.order:])
            newWord = r.choice(self.graph[orginalState])
            startingWords.append(newWord)
            var = i + 3
        return ''.join(startingWords[self.order:])

text = MarkovAlgorithm(order)
text.train(data)
result = text.generate(length)
#print ("Viola! Our bot created a story from ",title, " by ",author)
print (result)
```

The error that I was getting was

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\-------", line 37, in <module>
    result = text.generate(length)
  File "C:\-------", line 30, in generate
    newWord = r.choice(self.graph[orginalState])
KeyError: ('society', 'for', 's')
```

Comment: you didn't copy the indentation of the code (spaces or tabs in front of lines), it is essential for python code to work.

Comment: Can you include the actual error messages you got?

Comment: @WNG sorry for the indentation, I think there was a problem while copying or pasting

Comment: @SpoonMeiser I added the error in the question.

Comment: This sets up `self.text` and `self.words` and it looks like it _always_ wants `self.words`, but mixes them up and uses both.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser are you trying to say that I have mixed up self.text and self.words?

Comment: In the original source, there are not two separate attributes. Also you set the values of graph to be a string, and then try to append to it like it's a list. Then there are a bunch of other weird differences between this code and the code in the slides linked to the video you linked.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser I updated my script and I still get an error